# Using lookup template with dynamic variable [Ansible]

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I'am using the lookup template plugin in order to create a json with a dynamic variable *value1* that will be send as body in the http request.

The api is returning an error because my json isn't in the right syntax. Indeed it has been corrupted by changing the *value1* variable.

It seems that ansible is trying to add the string *value1* to a json structure *Settings.json* which create a corrupted json (Check the output)

**Settings.json**

```
{
  "FS": {
    "key1": "{{ value1 }}",
    "key2": "{{ value2 }}",
    "key3": "{{ value3 }}" 
  }
}
```

**Yaml tasks**

```
  - set_fact: 
      value1: "C:\\Users\\adminlocal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible.44q4u5lu.mtobuild\\SmokeTest"

  - debug: 
      var: event_settings
    vars: 
      event_settings: "{{ lookup('template', 'EventSettings.json.j2') | to_json }}"
```

**Output**

```
{
    "event_settings": "\"{\\n  \\\"FileSystem\\\": {\\n    \\\"MetadataPattern\\\": \\\"XPDM_MODEL_*.xml\\\",\\n    \\\"RelativeInputVault\\\": \\\"C:\\\\Users\\\\adminlocal\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\ansible.44q4u5lu.mtobuild\\\\SmokeTest\\\",\\n    \\\"RelativeOutputVault\\\": \\\"OUTPUT\\\" \\n  },\\n  \\\"SessionManifest\\\": {\\n    \\\"EffectivityMode\\\": \\\"PureBSF\\\",\\n    \\\"NamePrefix\\\": \\\"prefix\\\"\\n  }, \\n  \\\"MessageBroker\\\": \\\"ActiveMQ\\\"\\n} \""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a backslash to escape the character backslash itself in your value1?

```
- name: my task
  set_fact: 
    value1: "C:\\\\Users\\\\adminlocal\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\ansible.44q4u5lu.mtobuild\\\\SmokeTest"
    value2: "abc"
    value3: "123"

- name: debug
  vars:
    event_settings: "{{ lookup('template', 'EventSettings.json.j2') | to_json }}"
  debug: 
    var: event_settings
```

EventSettings.json.j2:

```
{
  "FS": {
    "key1": "{{ value1 }}",
    "key2": "{{ value2 }}",
    "key3": "{{ value3 }}" 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
"event_settings": {
    "FS": {
        "key1": "C:\\Users\\adminlocal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible.44q4u5lu.mtobuild\\SmokeTest",
        "key2": "abc",
        "key3": "123"
    }
  }
}
```